# Lua function to see if a macro is defined or not

Tags: macros, luatex, lua

I need to determine if a TeX macro is already defined or not via a Lua function. Any ideas?

```lua
function IsTeXMacroDefined(macroname)
   if defined(macroname) then return true end
   return false
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know how robust it is but the following seems to work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\def\test{}

\begin{document}

\directlua{%
  function is_defined(s)
    local undef = 'undefined_cs'
    if token.command_name(token.create(s)) == undef then
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
  if is_defined('test') then tex.sprint('test is defined\noexpand\\par') else
  tex.sprint('test is not defined\noexpand\\par') end  
  if is_defined('testa') then tex.sprint('testa is defined\noexpand\\par') else
  tex.sprint('testa is not defined\noexpand\\par') end}

\end{document}
```

---

**Updated**

I added a `TeX` wrapper. It takes as an argument the name of the control sequence to be tested or the control sequence itself (this is done by removing the backslash at lua level with the help of `lpeg`). The `TeX` wrapper uses the expandability of `\directlua` to define on the fly a `TeX` `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` statement inside a `\csname`.

As pointed out in comments, one should always write lua code in a separate lua file.

First the lua file (save it as `is_def.lua`).

```lua
local lpeg = require('lpeg')
local P, C, Cs, V, match = lpeg.P, lpeg.C, lpeg.Cs, lpeg.V, lpeg.match

function is_cs_defined (s)
   s = match(Cs(P({(C('\\') / '' + 1) * V(1) + true})),s)
   local undef = 'undefined_cs'
   return not(token.command_name(token.create(s)) == undef)
end
```

Then the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\directlua{dofile('is_def.lua')}

\def\iscsdefined#1{%
  \texttt{\string#1} 
  \csname if\directlua{if is_cs_defined('\luatexluaescapestring{#1}')
  then tex.sprint('true') else tex.sprint('false') end}\endcsname
    is defined
  \else
    is not defined
  \fi}

\def\test{}

\begin{document}

\iscsdefined{test}

\iscsdefined{\test}

\iscsdefined{testa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This will probably work good enough. You'll need to use no expand on the `\\par` for the example to work though.

Comment: ... Or better put it into a Lua file :-)

Comment: Do you know whether it's possible to go further and get the actual definition this way?

Comment: ^ Answering above comment: yes, with `token.get_macro` and/or `token.get_meaning`